# How to put constrains on maximum selectable CheckBoxes via RadioButtons in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, radio-group

Please have a look at the picture below, you will understand the layout of my application.

[image]

I would like to have the possibility to dynamically choose how many `CheckBox` (which enable the drop down menus) are selectable (a fixed number). And I want to achieve this with those 3 `RadioButton`.

In the vertical Mode all 4 `CheckBox` must be selected (not less). In the Hybrid mode only 2 `CheckBox` must be available (not more and not less). In the Horizontal mode only 1 `CheckBox` must be selected (not more). It is important that the user has the capability to choose a specific combination `ComboBox`es (eg: we are in the hybrid mode, choosing 1 and 2 is different than choosing 1 and 3).

**Solution**

```
public class ConfigurationEditDialogController {

// Data Acquisition Tab

private ObservableList<String> options =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "ciao",
                "hello",
                "halo"
        );

@FXML
private PrefixSelectionComboBox<String> testBus1ComboBox = new PrefixSelectionComboBox<>();
@FXML
private PrefixSelectionComboBox<String> testBus2ComboBox = new PrefixSelectionComboBox<>();
@FXML
private PrefixSelectionComboBox<String> testBus3ComboBox = new PrefixSelectionComboBox<>();
@FXML
private PrefixSelectionComboBox<String> testBus4ComboBox = new PrefixSelectionComboBox<>();
@FXML
private CheckBox checkbox1;
@FXML
private CheckBox checkbox2;
@FXML
private CheckBox checkbox3;
@FXML
private CheckBox checkbox4;

private ObservableSet<CheckBox> selectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableSet();
private ObservableSet<CheckBox> unselectedCheckBoxes = FXCollections.observableSet();

private IntegerBinding numCheckBoxesSelected = Bindings.size(selectedCheckBoxes);
private int maxNumSelected =  2;

@FXML
private RadioButton verticalMode;
@FXML
private RadioButton horizontalMode;
@FXML
private RadioButton hybridMode;


private Stage dialogStage;
private Configuration configuration;
private boolean okClicked = false;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
 * after the fxml file has been loaded.
 */
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    testBus1ComboBox.setItems(options);
    testBus2ComboBox.setItems(options);
    testBus3ComboBox.setItems(options);
    testBus4ComboBox.setItems(options);
    configureCheckBox(checkbox1);
    configureCheckBox(checkbox2);
    configureCheckBox(checkbox3);
    configureCheckBox(checkbox4);

    numCheckBoxesSelected.addListener((obs, oldSelectedCount, newSelectedCount) -> {
        if (newSelectedCount.intValue() >= maxNumSelected) {
            unselectedCheckBoxes.forEach(cb -> cb.setDisable(true));
        } else {
            unselectedCheckBoxes.forEach(cb -> cb.setDisable(false));
        }
    });


    testBus1ComboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkbox1.selectedProperty().not());
    testBus2ComboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkbox2.selectedProperty().not());
    testBus3ComboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkbox3.selectedProperty().not());
    testBus4ComboBox.disableProperty().bind(checkbox4.selectedProperty().not());

}


private void configureCheckBox(CheckBox checkBox) {

    if (checkBox.isSelected()) {
        selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
    } else {
        unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
    }

    checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {
        if (isNowSelected) {
            unselectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
            selectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
        } else {
            selectedCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
            unselectedCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
        }

    });

}
```

**Tab of `FXML` File**
I would like to implement fabian solution in this tab, however It is not needed to use an fxml as I did.

```
<Tab closable="false" text="Data Acquisition">
           <content>
                <GridPane prefHeight="254.0" prefWidth="404.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="218.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="111.0" />
                        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="519.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="490.0" />
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="316.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="71.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Test Bus 1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Test Bus 2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Test Bus 3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                        <Label text="Test Bus 4" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                    <PrefixSelectionComboBox fx:id="testBus1ComboBox" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="300.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                    <PrefixSelectionComboBox fx:id="testBus2ComboBox" prefWidth="300.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                    <PrefixSelectionComboBox fx:id="testBus3ComboBox" prefWidth="300.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                    <PrefixSelectionComboBox fx:id="testBus4ComboBox" prefWidth="300.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="checkbox1" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="checkbox2" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="checkbox3" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
                    <CheckBox fx:id="checkbox4" mnemonicParsing="false" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
                    <Label text="Sample Mode" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    <RadioButton fx:id="verticalMode" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Vertical " GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                       <toggleGroup>
                          <ToggleGroup fx:id="SampleModeGroup" />
                       </toggleGroup>
                    </RadioButton>
                    <RadioButton fx:id="hybridMode" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hybrid" toggleGroup="$SampleModeGroup" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    <RadioButton fx:id="horizontalMode" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Horizontal" toggleGroup="$SampleModeGroup" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    </children>
                </GridPane>
           </content>
        </Tab>
```

I have only managed to set manually which number is the maximum (but not the minimum) allowed using `private int maxNumSelected = 2;`. However I would like to manipulate them via `RadioButton`.

Comment: You could implement a listener on the `RadioButtons` and disable or enable the check boxes and comboboxes based on the selection.

Comment: I know, I tried but I am doing something wrong and I am getting exceptions. I don't know why.

Comment: Add the code that is throwing the exception, and also add the exception stack trace to your question.

Comment: Another, better, option would be to use `Bindings` to bind each combobox/check box to the `Selected` property of the appropriate `RadioButton`. I'll add an answer below with a sample.

Comment: Now I do not have, because I tried some hours ago and then I removed it. but if you want I can try to code it again, but if you know how to do it you can try to give me some advice. Because I feel that my implementation misses just this link between the parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend hardcoding the `CheckBox`es/`ComboBox`es and counts for the cases in different places. Use the same value for both creating the `CheckBox`es/`ComboBox`es and modifying the allowed number of selected `CheckBox`es. However this pervents you from creating the look in fxml alone.

Unless you want some pretty confusing behavior for the user, you need to allow the user to select less than the required number of `CheckBox`es though, since you cannot really tell which `CheckBox` to select when unselecting one. You could disable/enable a button for submitting the form or some similar control though...

```
private static HBox createModesRadios(IntegerProperty count, Mode... modes) {
    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    HBox result = new HBox(10);
    for (Mode mode : modes) {
        RadioButton radio = new RadioButton(mode.getText());
        radio.setToggleGroup(group);
        radio.setUserData(mode);
        result.getChildren().add(radio);
    }
    if (modes.length > 0) {
        group.selectToggle((Toggle) result.getChildren().get(0));
        count.bind(Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> ((Mode) group.getSelectedToggle().getUserData()).getCount(), group.selectedToggleProperty()));
    } else {
        count.set(0);
    }
    return result;
}

private static void updateCheckBoxes(CheckBox[] checkBoxes, int requiredCount, int unmodifiedIndex) {
    if (unmodifiedIndex >= 0 && checkBoxes[unmodifiedIndex].isSelected()) {
        requiredCount--;
    }
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length && requiredCount > 0; i++) {
        if (i != unmodifiedIndex && checkBoxes[i].isSelected()) {
            requiredCount--;
        }
    }

    for (; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (i != unmodifiedIndex) {
            checkBoxes[i].setSelected(false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Mode[] modes = new Mode[]{
        new Mode("Vertical", 4),
        new Mode("Hybrid", 2),
        new Mode("Horizontal", 1)
    };

    ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
    IntegerProperty elementCount = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

    HBox radioBox = createModesRadios(elementCount, modes);
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    VBox root = new VBox(10, radioBox);

    int count = Stream.of(modes).mapToInt(Mode::getCount).max().orElse(0);
    ObservableMap<Integer, String> elements = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "ciao",
            "hello",
            "halo");

    CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[count];

    elementCount.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // uncheck checkboxes, if too many are checked
        updateCheckBoxes(checkBoxes, newValue.intValue(), -1);
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final Integer index = i;
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBoxes[i] = checkBox;

        ComboBox<String> comboBox = new ComboBox<>(options);
        comboBox.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            // modify value in map on value change
            elements.put(index, newValue);
        });
        comboBox.setDisable(true);

        checkBox.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            comboBox.setDisable(!newValue);
            if (newValue) {
                // put the current element in the map
                elements.put(index, comboBox.getValue());

                // uncheck checkboxes that exceede the required count keeping the current one unmodified
                updateCheckBoxes(checkBoxes, elementCount.get(), index);
            } else {
                elements.remove(index);
            }

        });
        grid.addRow(i, comboBox, checkBox);
    }

    Button submit = new Button("submit");
    submit.setOnAction(evt -> System.out.println(elements));

    // enable submit button iff the number of elements is correct
    submit.disableProperty().bind(elementCount.isNotEqualTo(Bindings.size(elements)));

    root.getChildren().addAll(grid, submit);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```
public class Mode {

    private final String text;
    private final int count;

    public Mode(String text, int count) {
        this.text = text;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: I probably forgot to mention that the checkboxes allow me to choose a specific `ComboBox`. This probably is why I need them, because choosing 1 and 3 is different than choosing 2 and 3. I will edit the question

Comment: Thanks I tried to run your code and It is exact what I need, however I would like to implement this solution in my controller class. Now I will try, do you have any particular suggestion? Since I have my fxml built via ScenBuilder

Comment: Edited the questions with `fxml` file. However I would really like to populate my `GridPane` using your methods.

Comment: I have managed to add your solution into the container of my `fxml` `Tab`. Then how can I adjust the layout of the elements created by your code? Also Is still ok if I want to add some more elements into the fxml? I am not very good with the layout through JavaFX, that is why I am using SceneBuilder

Comment: You could create the "surrounding structure" in fxml and use the `initialize` method to "fill in the blanks". If you're not familiar enough to use the layouts properly without the help of SceneBuilder, you could still design the UI in SceneBuilder and take a look at the resulting fxml (as text). It shouldn't be too hard to do the proper node creations / assignments for properties based on the fxml... It greatly helps you to know how the layouts work even with fxml. Otherwise you probably don't create a scene that is responsive to resizing...

Comment: Ok I imagined this, I am trying this approach. Anyway one thing is not clear, If I might need the values inside the `ComboBox`es, because I need to perform operations with: how can I collect them?

Comment: The `elements` `ObservableMap` contains one key for each selected checkbox and the value the key is mapped to is the value selected in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen it. Never used `ObservableMap` before, but it came really in handy. In addition do you know how can I call those `ComboBox`es to set a value there? Do you suggest to insert them too in some sort of `Array` in order to call them?

Comment: I want to populate again the view with the parameters previously stored following an use of the. I think I have to remember the choice of the `RadioButton`, then the `CheckBox`es and in the end using `.setValue()` on the `ComboBox`es. Right?

Comment: How can i call in another method the selected `RadioBox`?

Comment: What if I would like to `.setSelected(true)` all the `CheckBox`es and disable them in case of *Vertical Mode* selected via `RadioButton`s.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a listener on all of your `RadioButton` and when one is selected, disable or enable the containers for each of your `ComboBox`/`CheckBox` nodes.

Here is a sample application that demonstrates this. I built the UI with pure Java (no FXML) just to keep everything in one posting. The important part is the the three listeners added to the `RadioButtons`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        // Root layout
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Radio buttons
        HBox hbRadios = new HBox(10);
        hbRadios.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ToggleGroup tglRadioSelections = new ToggleGroup();
        RadioButton rdoVertical = new RadioButton("Vertical");
        RadioButton rdoHybrid = new RadioButton("Hybrid");
        RadioButton rdoHorizontal = new RadioButton("Horizontal");
        tglRadioSelections.getToggles().addAll(rdoVertical, rdoHybrid, rdoHorizontal);
        hbRadios.getChildren().addAll(rdoVertical, rdoHybrid, rdoHorizontal);

        // ComboBoxes and CheckBoxes
        VBox vbSelections = new VBox(10);
        ComboBox cbo1 = new ComboBox();
        ComboBox cbo2 = new ComboBox();
        ComboBox cbo3 = new ComboBox();
        ComboBox cbo4 = new ComboBox();
        CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox chk2 = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox chk3 = new CheckBox();
        CheckBox chk4 = new CheckBox();

        // Create the containers for each selection group
        HBox hbSelection1 = new HBox(10);
        hbSelection1.getChildren().addAll(cbo1, chk1);
        HBox hbSelection2 = new HBox(10);
        hbSelection2.getChildren().addAll(cbo2, chk2);
        HBox hbSelection3 = new HBox(10);
        hbSelection3.getChildren().addAll(cbo3, chk3);
        HBox hbSelection4 = new HBox(10);
        hbSelection4.getChildren().addAll(cbo4, chk4);

        // Add listeners for each radio button to enable appropriate selections
        rdoVertical.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                hbSelection1.setDisable(!newValue);
                hbSelection2.setDisable(!newValue);
                hbSelection3.setDisable(!newValue);
                hbSelection4.setDisable(!newValue);
        });
        rdoHybrid.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            hbSelection1.setDisable(!newValue);
            hbSelection2.setDisable(!newValue);
            hbSelection3.setDisable(!newValue);
            hbSelection4.setDisable(newValue);
        });
        rdoHorizontal.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            hbSelection1.setDisable(!newValue);
            hbSelection2.setDisable(newValue);
            hbSelection3.setDisable(newValue);
            hbSelection4.setDisable(newValue);
        });

        // Build the scene
        vbSelections.getChildren().addAll(hbSelection1, hbSelection2, hbSelection3, hbSelection4);
        root.getChildren().addAll(hbRadios, vbSelections);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Just a couple of things to note. You will need named containers to enable/disable the appropriate selection areas. Here they are called `hbSelection#`, which is where we add the checkboxes and comboboxes.

In the listeners, you will see I am basically just setting each HBox's disabled property based on `newValue` which is `true` if the `RadioButton` is selected and `false` if it is not.

There may be a more efficient way of handling this, but this is definitely one method.

Comment: How can I let the user choose the `CheckBox`es? For example, choosing the first two `CheckBox`es (hence the first two `ComboBox`es) is different than choosing the first one and the third one

Comment: In that case, just add the check boxes to a group and then iterate over the group's members and count the number of selected checkboxes...?

Comment: Still can't solve. Looking at my code, I want a way that `maxNumSelected` is 1, 2, or 4 depending on which `RadioButton` is selected. How can i do this, so I do not need to re invent my implementation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with reinventing your implementation if the implementation is wrong :P