# Restrict checkboxes checked. Javafx

Tags: javafx, checkbox

How to restrict the number of checkboxes that a user can select? I want to make it so the user can only select 3. I think I should use isSelected, but I don't know how to link all the checkboxes.

```
    CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox("Pepperoni");
    CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox("Cheese");
    CheckBox cb3 = new CheckBox("Tomato");
    CheckBox cb4 = new CheckBox("Olives");
    CheckBox cb5 = new CheckBox("Chicken");
    //if 3 are already selected, it should not be possible for the user to select more
```

Comment: Help please! I feel like it is simple, but I can't find the solution!

Comment: looks like you didn't even try to come up with a solution - typically that's considered a prerequisitive for getting answers (please read the help pages on how to post a question :)

Comment: and please refrain from posting the exact same question (except this being even worse than the other) twice! If you feel in dire need of getting an answer immediately, consider hiring a consultant ;)

Comment: What kleopatra said - or just try actually searching SO first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970771/how-to-put-constrains-on-maximum-selectable-checkboxes-via-radiobuttons-in-javaf/50971280#50971280

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put constrains on maximum selectable CheckBoxes via RadioButtons in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50970771/how-to-put-constrains-on-maximum-selectable-checkboxes-via-radiobuttons-in-javaf)

Answer (score 2):

Simply keep track of the selected `CheckBox`es using a suitable data structure (`LinkedHashSet` would allow you to use `Set` functionality and allow you to determine the first one inserted).
Updating the data structure can be done from a listener to the `selected` properties of the `CheckBox`es.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    String[] ingredients = new String[]{
        "Pepperoni",
        "Cheese",
        "Tomato",
        "Olives",
        "Chicken"
    };
    final int maxCount = 3;
    final Set<CheckBox> activeBoxes = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = (o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        // get checkbox containing property
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) ((ReadOnlyProperty) o).getBean();

        if (newValue) {
            activeBoxes.add(cb);
            if (activeBoxes.size() > maxCount) {
                // get first checkbox to be activated
                cb = activeBoxes.iterator().next();

                // unselect; change listener will remove
                cb.setSelected(false);
            }
        } else {
            activeBoxes.remove(cb);
        }
    };

    VBox root = new VBox();

    // create checkboxes
    for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(ingredients[i]);
        cb.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
        root.getChildren().add(cb);
    }

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

**Note:** If you want the user to be simply unable to select more `CheckBox`es when there are 3 selected, simply disable all unselected `CheckBox`es when you reach 3 selected `CheckBox`es:

```
final CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[ingredients.length];

ChangeListener<Boolean> listener = new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

    private int activeCount = 0;

    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> o, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        if (newValue) {
            activeCount++;
            if (activeCount == maxCount) {
                // disable unselected CheckBoxes
                for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                    if (!cb.isSelected()) {
                        cb.setDisable(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (activeCount == maxCount) {
                // reenable CheckBoxes
                for (CheckBox cb : checkBoxes) {
                    cb.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
            activeCount--;
        }
    }
};

VBox root = new VBox();

// create checkboxes
for (int i = 0; i < ingredients.length; i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(ingredients[i]);
    cb.selectedProperty().addListener(listener);
    root.getChildren().add(cb);
    checkBoxes[i] = cb;
}
```